# VS Express 2015 - NUnit doesn't find automated tests

Tags: c#, automation, nunit, visual-studio-express

I've built an automation solution recently, and I am not allowed to install VS Community at work. I want to use my solution in VS Express 2015.

However, the issue is, that my VS doesn't find the tests. I tried installing NUnit (v3.8.1) + NUnit3TestAdapter (v3.8.0). Also tried different other solutions. I couldn't make it work unfortunately.

Do you think it is possible in any way to make NUnit find my tests in VS Express 2015? Thanks!

Comment: What version of `.NET` your application use ? If >4.5, try to change it to that version. Also this may be helpful http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-execute-invoke-nunit-from-visual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Express does not support extensions, so cannot run tests within the IDE. You must run tests from the command line. As a free product, it is intentionally limited.

You can legally use Visual Studio Community if your company has up to five developers using it, makes less than $1 Million in revenue **and** has less than 250 computers within the company. If your company is large enough to not qualify for Visual Studio Community licensing, then they are large enough to pay for Visual Studio Professional.

Comment: I know, but I'm learning C# Automation in my free time, I doubt they would pay a license for VS. I'll figure something out, or I'll move to Eclipse IDE ~ Java Automation. Much Obliged!

Comment: If you are just learning, you can run and debug C# .NET Core tests for free in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio 2017 Express and the NUnit3TestAdapter NuGet.